# Message Type: Heading and Range

Tags: ros, range, message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you have a sensor with a beacon, which gives you the distance and the heading ( maybe Quaternion ) to the beacon, is there already a standard ROS message I could use for that?

Regards,

Christian

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223620/message-type:-heading-and-range/) by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1376 on 2016-01-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well after some thinking, I guess I found an answer to that now.
Probably the answer is just a point in the frame of the sensor.
I just have polar coordinates then and I have to transform them into cartesian coordinates.

So I think it will be geometry_msgs/PointStamped then, with frame_id sensor_link.
Where x is looking in the direction of the sensors front.

---

Originally posted by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) with karma: 1376 on 2016-01-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-01-07**:
`Point`s don't have a 'direction'?

**Comment by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) on 2016-01-08**:
Yes, but actually in the sensors frame it would result in one. Thinking of the sensor as origin. You get an angle for the z axis and a distance to it -> so it is like a polar coordinate you could translate in x and y. Actually I am also not sure if this resolves my problem. Because it is not ...

**Comment by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) on 2016-01-08**:
really a heading I get. It is the ir-sensor from the EV3 which can detect it's infrared beacon. I need to test around with it how this works out. I think it could be used as a source for localization when using two of the beacons. http://www.ev3dev.org/docs/sensors/lego-ev3-infrared-sensor/ ...

**Comment by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) on 2016-01-08**:
(see IR Seeker mode)